# Trying to combine two VBA scripts into one

Tags: vba

I am very new to VBA Scripts. I have been googling trying to figure out how to combine these together and assign a button to run this.

My first script I am adding a sequence number and row to a table. The table is two columns B:C. My numbering is looking at the row below the line I am inserting to keep the numbers in sequential order. (I found this on Youtube works great)

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()



Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Select
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4:C4").Select
    Selection.Borders.Weight = xlThin

    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "=B5+1"

End Sub
```

Second one is applying a timestamp to C4 which is giving a timestamp to the sequential number.

```
Private Sub timeStamp()
    Dim ts As Date

    With Range("C4")
        .Value = Now
        .NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"
      End With
End Sub
```

I cannot figure out how to make these two run together. Individually they work.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: within a subroutine, you can call another subroutine to run by just writing the name, e.g., `timeStamp`, as a standalone line.  This works if they are in the same module.  You can use `application.run()` if you are using separate modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you just paste the code of the second in the first (*and a few other adjustments*):

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim ts As Date

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("B4").EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    .Range("B4:C4").Borders.Weight = xlThin
    .Range("B4").Value= "=B5+1"

    With .Range("C4")
        .Value = Now
        .NumberFormat = "h:mm:ss AM/PM"
    End With

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: AAA This worked great Thank you very much. I am already signed up for class. I knew I had a lot to learn.